# fill blank values of one dataframe with the values of another dataframe based on conditions-pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have above dataframe df,and I have following dataframe as df2

[image]

I want to fill missing values in df with values in df2 corresponding to the id.
Also for Player1,Player2,Player3.If the value is missing.I want to replace Player1,Player2,Player3 of df with the corresponding values of df2.
Thus the resultant dataframe would look like this
[image]

Notice.Rick,Scott,Andrew are still forward as they are in df.I just replaced players in df with the corresponding players in df2. 
So far,I have attempted to fill the blank values in df with the values in df2.

```
df=pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
for s in list(df.columns[1:]):
   df[s]=df[s].str.strip()
df.fillna('',inplace=True)
df.replace(r'',np.nan,regex=True,inplace=True)
df2=pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
for s in list(df2.columns[1:]):
  df2[s]=df2[s].str.strip()
df.set_index('Team ID',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('Team ID',inplace=True)
df.fillna(df2,inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

[image]

I am getting above result.How can I get result in Image Number 3?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
df1=df1.set_index('Team ID')
df2=df2.set_index('Team ID')

df2=df2.combine_first(df1.replace('',np.nan)).reset_index()
```